# Conditional tag-like function to tell if post is in trash?

Tags: conditional-tags, post-status, trash

What could I put in my theme to tell if a post is in the trash or not?

For example:

```
<?php if (is_trash) echo 'This post is in the trash!' ?>
```

Comment: Still not solved? Or just abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`get_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status):

```
function is_trash( $post_id = 0 )
{
    0 == $post_id and $post_id = get_the_ID();
    return 'trash' === get_post_status( $post_id );
}
```

Side note: To get a list of all registered post status objects use `get_post_stati()` – yes, that's [wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/877/7699).